# How to query parameters from http client and send it to node js server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, rest, express

I've tried googling everything but I cannot seem to find a way of sending query param to a get request. Here is the node js server side code:

```
let propertiesObject = {q: 'lord of the rings'};
let url = https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?key=totallyalegitkey

request({url:url, qs:propertiesObject}, function(err, response, body) {
if(err) { console.log(err); return; } console.log("Get response: " + response.statusCode); console.log(response); });
```

This is the closest I've gotten to "querying" but the problem is I need to update propertiesObject from html client and I have no idea how to do that....

Answer (score 0):

You can create a URL object and set your query params through searchParams.

```
let url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?key=totallyalegitkey");

url.searchParams.set("q", "lord of the rings");

request(url.href, function(err, response, body) {
    if(err) { console.log(err); return; }
    console.log("Get response: " + response.statusCode);
    console.log(response);
});
```